# How To Load Selected Contact Into a Text Box in a Android Native App Built with HTML5

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, telerik

I am building a HTML5 based Android App for SMS messaging, that is, I build the app using HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, Jquery, then an gonna use Telerik or PhoneGap to convert it to an APK.

I need to have a feature on the app that will allow users pick a contact form their phone book and have the selected contact loaded in a text box.

I have the following codes somewhere within my HTML to do the job

```
    <input type="text" id="number">
    <button id="pickContact">Phonebook</button>

    <script>
var pickContact = document.getElementById('pickCntact')
pickContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
        @Override
        public void onClick(View g) {
            Intent q = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(q, 1001);  

        }
    });


//and to handle the result (which is referenced by 1001) use this:

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);  

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
        // getting the URI from result for further working
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {


          String  id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

          String hasPhone =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));



          if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
          Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
                          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
                          null, null);
                phones.moveToFirst();
                  //this string will hold the contact number
                  String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                  document.getElementById('number').value = cNumber;
              }

        }} 
    } 
    </script>
```

I have also added the necessary permissions on my manifest file, thus.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

The problem now is that nothing happens when i click the "phonebok" button.

Please could anyone help me out. I am new in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution and am sharing it just in case someone out there is in need of similar solution.

A was able to call-up a contact selector and instantly load the default phone number of a selected contact into my text box using a codava plugin, which is auto included on Telerik projects.

Firstly, i reference the codava within my HTML

```
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Then i have this script to call the codava's pickContact plugin when the load contact button is pressed;

```
    $('#myActionButton').click(function() {
        navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact) {
            var numberC = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value;
            $('#myTextBox').val(numberC);
       }, function(err) {
          alert(err);
        });
  });
```

More information on Codava plugins can be found at http://phonegap-plugins.com/

Hope this will be useful to someone else